# how to retrieve the name and value in object list

Tags: javascript, list, object

The object list is looks like that in Javascript

```
Object {Not In Build Scope: 37, Incomplete: 1}
```

I am not sure how to get the "Not In Build Scope", "Incomplete" and their value.

Please kindly help.

Comment: `Object.keys(objectName)` will give all keys, and you can iterate over it and get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get the keys of that object and with each key, you can get the corresponding values, like this

```
> var dataObject = {
...     "Not In Build Scope": 37,
...     "Incomplete": 1
... };
> var keys = Object.keys(dataObject);
> var values = keys.map(function(key) {
...     return dataObject[key];
... });
> keys
[ 'Not In Build Scope', 'Incomplete' ]
> values
[ 37, 1 ]
```